# Can a Spring Cloud Stream Kinesis consumer group be sent by a non-Spring producer?

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

In our environment, we have a producer that is not a Spring microservice sending Avro messages over Kinesis to a Spring Cloud microservice. My question is how can the non-Spring producer add the consumer group message header to each message so that the Spring microservice can scale up to more than one instance, ensuring that the Spring microservices do not consume each message more than once?

Can this be done in Kinesis, and if so, are there any code examples anyone can point me to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say "Not clear what you're asking", but I'll try to explain what might be wrong.

The *Consumer Group* is an abstraction, well..., for consumers. The producer has nothing to know about that abstraction. It's point just send messages to the destination and forget.

One of main goals of the consumer group abstraction is to ensure that message is processed only in one consumer meanwhile there might be more than one consumer in a group.

There is a feature in AWS Kinesis complementing consumer group abstraction. It is *sharding* in Kinesis streams. With consumer group implementation in Spring Cloud Stream, there is a trick to distribute shards between consumers in a group, so they can be processed in parallel.

Here you really can benefit fro sharding saying to your producer to which one to send a record. See more info about `partitionKey` in Kinesis Producer API.

Comment: What is the purpose of spring.cloud.stream.bindings.channel_name.producer.required-groups then? My understanding, maybe incorrectly, is that this property is required on the producer side to ensure that the message is delivered with the correct consumer group specified. I have microservices where the producer has this property specified and the consumer has the spring.cloud.stream.bindings.channel_name.group that has the same value. Is that not the case? Are you saying that the producer's spring.cloud.stream.bindings.channel_name.producer.required-groups property isn't even required?

Comment: The `required-groups` is applied only in the non-partitioned binders, like RabbitMQ, which message store doesn't provide a *partitioning* concept. In case of Kinesis we have shards in streams, so there is nothing to do on the producer side about groups. You are free to produce to the Kinesis stream from any producer and consume records by the Spring Cloud Stream solution. Only bear in mind that `headerMode` must be turned off on that Spring Cloud Stream consumer. By default it is an `embeddedHeaders` and i believe you won't be able to ensure embedding headers in your non-Spring producer.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you saying that headerMode must be turned off when consuming Kinesis streams? What is the exact property and value I need to set on my Kinesis consumer?

Comment: See Docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_consumer_properties: `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.<channelName>.consumer.headerMode=none`, where you use your own channel name, typically it is an `input` one.